# Eloquent has query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this error :

```
in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given (View: C:\wamp64\www\partie2-exo\resources\views\index.blade.php)
```

Here is the line in question :

```
{!! link_to_route('poll.edit', 'Modifier', [$poll->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-block' . (in_array($poll->question, $polls_voted)? ' disabled' : '')]) !!}
```

This error comes from the PollRepository :

```
$polls_voted = Poll::has('answers')->get();
```

The values ​​of "polls_voted" should be the questions for which there were votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$polls_voted` in your case is a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections). An easy fix for this would be to `pluck()` all the questions and convert it to an array with `toArray()`.

```
{!! link_to_route('poll.edit', 'Modifier', [$poll->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-block' . (in_array($poll->question, $polls_voted->pluck('question')->toArray()) ? ' disabled' : '')]) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IN_ARRAY()` accept parameter 2 to be array. The passed array should be non-assosiative like this  `$arr = ["one","two","three"]`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Eloquent Builder, you get an object. That is'nt an array, so in_array won't work. Instead of that, you can use `toArray()` to change it into an array. Like these 2 examples

```
$user = App\User::with('roles')->first();

return $user->toArray();


$users = App\User::all();

return $users->toArray();
```

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization